# Has anyone ever heard of a Bresthaven Dragon-Fly III?

Tags: airplane, aviation-in-fiction, records

In James Thurber’s classic short story The Greatest Man In The World, the main character, lowlife hooligan Jack ‘Pal’ Smurch, attains the heights of fame when he flies an airplane around the world without stopping.  The type of airplane which he flies is described by Thurber as a “Bresthaven Dragon-Fly III monoplane” and is a “ridiculous contraption”.  While the story is fiction, certain details, such as Smurch’s takeoff and landing at the now defunct Roosevelt Field on Long Island, NY are real places.  I have never heard of a Bresthaven Dragonfly III aircraft, nor that manufacturer.  I suspect the airplane is fictional, but it might be an older era reference to an actual artifact, similar to calling KJFK Idlewylde Airport, etc. Has anyone ever heard of this aircraft type?

Comment: Breasthaven might be a real supplier, but more in the... in-flight entertainment direction.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Bresthaven Dragonfly III, nor is Bresthaven an airplane manufacturer.

Comment: That's what I get for reading @therac's comment!